# Collect statistics for a single partition in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table which has the primary key on one column and is partitioned by a date column. This is sample format of the DDL:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DB.TABLE_NAME,
NO FALLBACK ,
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
NO AFTER JOURNAL,
CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
(  FIRST_KEY                 DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL,
   SECOND_KEY                DECIMAL(20,0) ,
   THIRD_COLUMN              VARCHAR(5),     
   DAY_DT                    DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
PRIMARY INDEX TABLE_NAME_IDX_PR (FIRST_KEY)
PARTITION BY RANGE_N(DAY_DT  BETWEEN DATE '2007-01-06' 
                                 AND DATE '2016-01-02' EACH  INTERVAL '1' DAY );

COLLECT STATS ON DB.TABLE_NAME COLUMN(FIRST_KEY);
```

The incoming data can be of size 30 million each day and I have loaded the data for 2012-04-11. Now i have to collect stats for only '2012-04-11' partition instead of whole table.

Is there any way to collect partition for a particular day?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply collect stats on the system column `PARTITION` and it should update the histograms relating to the partitioned column.

```
COLLECT STATS ON {databasename}.{tablename} COLUMN (PARTITION);
```

This can be collected on both partitioned and non-partitioned tables. It helps provided the optimizer cardinality of the table and partitions (if they exist). It will update the statistics for all the partitions on the table. Collecting stats on the PARTITION column is a low CPU cost, short wall clock process. It is significantly less expensive than collecting stats on a physical column or the entire table. (Even for tables with millions, tens of millions or more records.)

If you want to determine whether the optimizer recognizes the refreshed statistics there is no direct way as of TD 13.10 (not sure about TD 14.x). However, if you run an EXPLAIN on your query you can tell if the optimizer has high confidence on the step which the criteria against the partitioned column is included. If you specify a single date, such as `DATE '2012-04-11'` you should see in the EXPLAIN that partition elimination has taken place on a single partition.

If you need help with digesting the EXPLAIN, edit your original question with the EXPLAIN plan for the query and I will help you digest it.

Comment: can we know only '2012-04-11' partition is analyzed by means? (sort of queries)

Comment: can we use the same 'COLLECT STATS ON {databasename}.{tablename} COLUMN (PARTITION)' for weekly partition also?

Comment: This can be used on any table, partitioned or not, in your database.

Comment: 'COLLECT STATS ON {databasename}.{tablename} COLUMN (PARTITION)' will it analyze on all the partitions loaded till then or only current days partition .

Comment: I also read something somewhere that suggests collecting stats on the partition plus the primary index column, i.e. `COLLECT STATS ON DB.TABLENAME COLUMN (PARTITION,FIRST_KEY)`.  Might be worthwhile investigating.

Comment: BellevueBob - Agreed. That would be a good thing to add to your routine maintenance script.